# Access denied from "shutil.rmtree('dir_path')", despite emptying dir_path's contents

Tags: python, shutil

The function "shutil.rmtree('dir_path') "  does remove the content of the folder, however,
it also throw  the exception as follow "[WinError 5] Access is denied: 'dir_path'"

```
from shutil import rmtree
my_folder = 'aaa/bbb/'
try:
    rmtree(my_folder)
except Exception as err:
    print (err)
```

Comment: `rmtree` also tries to remove the top-level `bbb` directory itself. If you don't have permission to do that, it will get an error.

Comment: how do i overcome this issue?